# HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument() cause error

Tags: c#, dll, reference, html-agility-pack

In my app I want to use `HTMLAgilityPack` which had been installed using NuGet. But when I try to create `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` instance, I've got

> "Source not found" error with HtmlDocument.cs.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

Solution Explorer->References does contain `HtmlAgilityPack`. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you put this in a class called `HtmlDocument`?

Comment: Try to uninstall and install HtmlAgilityPack again

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Nothing changes.

Comment: @Oded, hmm. No, I try this in 'public partial class Form1 :Form' Should I create special class called HtmlDocument? I'm new in C#.

Comment: @Akki no, you should not. Just reference to HtmlAgilityPack.dll should be added. Can you post full exception stack trace?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I havn't any exceptions, just this screen https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8288064/htmlagilityerror.png

Comment: @Akki I see that your HtmlAgilityPack.dll has RuntimeVersion 2, but it should be 4. Suppose that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your code throws an exception and the debugger tries to show you the code, or when you step into the call.

When you cancel the "Find Source" dialog for the first time, Visual Studio will add the source file path to an exception list and will not ask you again (This list is at: Solution Explorer->Right click on solution->Properties->Common Properties->Debug Source Files->Do not look for these source files).

In order to prevent the "HtmlDocument.cs not found" page from appearing when debugging, you need to step over (F10) the HtmlAgilityPack's calls instead of stepping into them (F11).

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your error by debugging code for a Windows Store app:

```csharp
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".htm");
StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var accessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(accessStream.AsStreamForRead());
```

If I set a breakpoint on the variable definition for the HtmlDocument, the error is thrown because HtmlDocument.cs will be looked for in a different partition. If I set a breakpoint after the last line, the error does not occur.

Might have something to do with asynchronous programming...